# Can "where" be used as "from which"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

In my high school English class, I learned that "where", "when", "how" can be used to replace "something+preposition+which" depending on the context. But I sometimes see sentences like

> New York is where I came from.

I asked my teacher, and she said it's equivalent to

> New York is the place from which I came from.

I don't believe this is correct! But I'm not sure. Is this correct? Can "where" be used as "from which" in this context? If not, what is the appropriate replacement for the "where" in the first sentence?

Comment: You definitely don't need a double "from" in "**from** which I came **from**". It's either "which I came from" or "from which I came." Also note that "where" is not replaced by "from which", but by "the place from which" or "the place which... from"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Lucky! But if "where" is replaced by "the place from which", why the double "from" unnecessary? If "the place from which" in "New York is the place from which I came" is replaced by "where", won't it be just "New York is where I came". Is that right?

Comment: Right, my mistake - "where from" is replaced by "the place from which" or "the place which... from" or better yet "where" refers to "the place which" - two "from" are not only unnecessary (another imprecision of mine, sorry about that) they are incorrect/ungrammatical. "There can be only one *from*" :-)

Comment: @Lucky I'm a little confused. What's "where" replacing in this context? I now know that two "from" is ungrammatical, so is it replacing other preposition?

Comment: The things get complicated because you have one relative pronoun *where* replacing "the place" but "the place" is further defined by a relative clause "which I came from". The fact is that grammar is not math - it is difficult to simply say: X replaces Y. Each construction is assessed on it's own, not relative to the other. So you don't look which element replaces the other one, but rather you look for the function of elements in a sentence. If I could put this more competently I'd construct a full answer, but I'm sure that there are some linguistic terms I'm lacking for that.

Comment: Do you think I should ask agian in ELU?

Comment: Cross-posting is very much frowned upon and this does seem like more of an ELL question - if you don't consider the answer you got to be satisfactory, you might edit your question to include further concerns, such as "which phrase does *where* correspond to in the 2nd sentence" or "why are two occurrences of *from* in the 2nd sentence ungrammatical" or other things that are sources of your concern. If that doesn't help in a few days (sometimes patience is necessary) ping me to look into it further :-).

Comment: There is an explanation about "from where" in Araucaria's answer here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/which-vs-where/34703#34703 does this answer your question, or would you like a different answer (and in what way different - simpler, more complex, more specific, more/less technical...)?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting syntax, though I've heard it's falling out of favor.

The purpose is to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition (from, to, on, etc).  So rather than say

> "...the car I am sitting in."

you would say

> "...the car in which I am sitting.".

This can be confusing, even for native speakers, so it is becoming less common.  I had a linguistics professor who used to say

> "A preposition is a fine thing to end a sentence *with*."

The "preferred" syntax (according to an English professor) would be

> "A preposition is a terrible thing *with which to end* a sentence"

which clearly sounds terrible.

Overall, you can impress people with your knowledge of this fancy syntax, but it often times will be more confusing than illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher seemed wrong definitely... The relative adverb where can be a noun meaning like a place so it means where I came from as the place which I came from, in which, the place which as same as where.

Comment: The teacher is correct - except for the repeated 'from'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).